# JSON Sharepoint Online different color for one symbol

Tags: json, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

)
hope someone can help me with my problem i have a sharepoint column with text and / looks like that:
bla bla bla / bla bla / bla
the slash i want to have in bold or different color
is it possible? i search everywhere but i cant find any solution
please help im a beginner
thank you so much for your time
Peggy

Answer (score -1):

Please use the below JSON formatting:

```
     {
     "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
     "elmType": "div",
     "txtContent": "@currentField",
     "style": {
         "background-color": "=if(Number(@currentField) == 0, '', if(@currentField >= @now + 2592000000, '#AFF8C9', if(@currentField >= @now + 86400000, '#EEBB2F', if(@currentField <= @now, '#F06C47',''))))",
         "font-weight": "bold" 
     }
 }
```

References:

[Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)
[CSS font-weight Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_weight.asp)

Comment: thank you so much but this is what i have already it makes the whole text with the slash bold i want to have just the slash bold or the text or different color :-)

Comment: Hi there. A number of MSFT contributors are sharing a piece of text to ask for votes, so it can be copy-pasted into answers. From this point forward I will downvote every time I see it. Please ask your colleagues to refrain from adding this - it is not welcome here.

Comment: This is the fifth question you have added it to, and it has been removed every time. Are you not seeing edits made to your material?